# Marklogic xdmp:log() in Query Console

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

Is it possible to view the output of xdmp:log() that was run directly from the query console, i.e. localhost:8000.

So if I had code like this:

```
let $c := "hello world"
return xdmp:log($c)
```

Where would I view the output for this log? I tried to check the log files in the Marklogic directory and it is not there. I also tried checking the console when I do "inspect element" and it is not there either. Is there another way, i.e. different function, I could use to view log outputs for the purposes of debugging code in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MarkLogic's error logs are grouped by the app servers' port assignments, so if Query Console is listening on port 8000, the error log you're looking for is `8000_ErrorLog.txt`. You should be able to find that in `MarkLogic/Logs` directory or browsing the `Logs` tab of the Admin Console on port 8001, e.g., `http://localhost:8001/get-error-log.xqy?filename=8000_ErrorLog.txt`.

Comment: Also, https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/manage/v2/logs accepts parameters for `start`, `end`, `regex`, `filename`